# LINQ query to get all objects of type

Tags: linq, distinct

I have a list of objects with a constant value property for each type. For example:

```
ObjectA : { Value: 5 }
ObjectB : { Value: 15 }
ObjectC : { Value: 2 }
```

In my object list, these objects can occur multiple times:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object> { ObjectA, ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC, ObjectC, ObjectC};
```

Now I want to sum all objects (by property Value), but I want a list of distinct objects like:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object> { ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC };
```

How can I realise that? Distinct() does not work in this case.

Thanks in advance!
Yheeky

Comment: If your types implement the `IEquatable` interface; or your types implement the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods; or you call the overload of `Distinct()` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance; then `Distinct()` will do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the objects by their type and take the first of each group:

```
var result = objects.GroupBy(o => o.GetType())
             .Select(g => g.First());
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *sum all objects (by property Value)*, but you could also do this:

```
var result = objects
            .GroupBy(o => o.GetType())
            .Select(g => new 
                         {
                             Object = g.Key.Name,
                             Sum = g.Sum(x => (int)(g.Key.GetProperty("Value")
                                                         .GetValue(x)))
                         });
```

Which will give an output like:

```
ObjectA 12
ObjectB 60
ObjectC 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a little on **Gert Arnold**'s answer, here is how to use [dynamics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) to get the sum from the distinct list of object types:

```
var a1 = new ObjectA(); //Value is 5
var a2 = new ObjectA(); //Value is 5
var b = new ObjectB(); //Value is 15
var c = new ObjectC(); //Value is 2

var list = new List<dynamic> { a1, a2, b, c };

var result = list
    .GroupBy(d => d.GetType())
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Sum(d => d.Value);
```

The resulting value is 22, not 27.

You can split this into separate steps if you want to maintain the list of distinct object types.